# Why does printing a map object as a list change the result of "in" (python 3.7.3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's some sample code. All I am trying to do is test the presence of an item inside a list. The list is created using the map function. The results change is I print the list first. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
In [20]: def f1():
    ...:     l = map(lambda x: x+'_1', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    ...:     if 'a_1' in l:
    ...:         return True
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return False
    ...:
    ...:

In [21]: def f2():
    ...:     l = map(lambda x: x+'_1', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    ...:     print(list(l))
    ...:     if 'a_1' in l:
    ...:         return True
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return False
    ...:
    ...:

In [22]: f1()
Out[22]: True

In [23]: f2()
['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
Out[23]: False
```

Comment: That's interesting, I tested it and found that `print(l)` instead of `print(list(l))` yields the expected behavior.

Comment: FWIW: `return 'a_1' in l`… Having an `if ...: return True else: return False` is always superfluous. (This is unrelated to the issue though.)

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
print(list(l))
```

The cast from `map` to `list` emtpies your map, try calling `print(list(l))` twice and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!